# What is the purpose of keeping filegroup or filestream backup in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, filestream

I'm a new DBA for SQL SERVER. Currently I'm learning about filestream on SQL server. So I tried to restore only filegroup of filestream to other database, but I get an error message:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> File 'testdb1' was not backed up in file 1 on device 'C:\data\New
>   folder\FSbackup.bak'. The file cannot be restored from this backup
>   set. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 3144)

Is it possible to restore only filestream to other database or restore only an old version of filestream to the current database of FILESTREAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I tried to restore only filegroup of filestream to other database, but I get an error message

As [Laughing Vergil](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/112791/laughing-vergil) originally mentioned in a comment, your question is answered in this great Stack Overflow post: [Restore filegroup to different database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208518/restore-filegroup-to-different-database)

The gist of the answer is that you *always* have to start by restoring the database with the PRIMARY filegroup.  Then you can restore additional filegroups (like the filestream one) after that.  This called a "piecemeal restore" and is [described in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/piecemeal-restores-sql-server).

> Is it possible to restore only filestream to other database

No, as mentioned above it needs to be restored along with the PRIMARY filegroup.

> or restore only an old version of filestream to the current database of FILESTREAM?

[Tibor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi) responded to this part in a comment.  The basic answer is "no."  This is because of the way database recovery works - you can't restore different parts of the database that are from different points in time.

As a side note, there is a restriction specifically related to filestream filegroups:

> If a partial restore sequence excludes any FILESTREAM filegroup, point-in-time restore is not supported.